# How do I get an element in a page which is an image without id or Name for Selenium automation testing?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

```
<a class="text-neutral-400 flex items-center gap-2 font-light px-3 py-2 text-[17px] font-[600] hover:bg-neutral-700 hover:no-underline active:bg-neutral-600 rounded-lg text-base" href="/leads"><span class="text-[40px]"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M20 7l-8-4-8 4m16 0l-8 4m8-4v10l-8 4m0-10L4 7m8 4v10M4 7v10l8 4"></path></svg></span><span class="hidden group-hover:flex">My Leads</span></a>
```

This is the details of the element that I want to chk onClick .But I couldn't find id or name here to get the element .How do I get the element?

I inspected an element which is an image and while clicking on this the page should go to a particular screen how do I identify this element by name or id?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the aforementioned details. You can edit your question and add a code sample.

Comment: I added the code sample but not getting displayed along with my post.Is it because I have some tags in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes .I used path to solve this
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/leads']"))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the svg image is wrapped inside an anchor tag. Which means it’s the anchor (link) that you most likely need to click. I would use the following cssSelector to identify it:

```
a[href=‘/leads’]
```

Comment: Yes I solved it with xpath.Thank u